# Regular hexagon sides as vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

So I'm having this problem (linear algebra).

Given that vector **a** is defined as **OA**, and **b** as **OB**. I need to express other ones in function of those ones.

I currently found that **BA** is **b-a** and **DE** is **-a+b** and also that **OD** is **-a** and **DA** is  **2a**. All using the definition of vectors. (I'm studying using Fraleigh's linear algebra.

But, the problem arise when trying to express **BC** cause I don't realize how. I now that since this is a regular hexagon the norm'll be the same as the **BA** and actually the other sides but can't express in terms of **a** and **b**.

Any help? Thanks.

[image: Regular Hexagon]

Comment: Remember that a vector has magnitude and direction, but not a fixed starting point. So with attention to sign you might look at a parallel vector you do know and work from there.

Comment: Thanks mark (didn't realize that of not starting point), so it'll be the same as **-a**?

Comment: Glad the hint helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that DO, OA, CB, EF are all the same vector $a$, but just moved across the plane. Similarly DE, CO, OF, BA are the same and are all $b-a$ ($b-a$ and $-a+b$, which you give for BA and DE, are of course the same), and DC, EO, OB and FA are all the same vector and are all $b$. And in particular, BC is -CB, so it is $-a$.

Comment: Thank you very much t-laarhoven. For the detailed explanation :)